# Gitで複数のブランチの更新を取り込む

Tags: git, github

Gitで複数のブランチの更新を手元に取り込むにはどうすればいいでしょうか?
例えばリモートのリポジトリはupstreamという名前で登録されており、リモートのリポジトリにmasterブランチ1つだけがあったとします。

この場合は

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream master
```

とすれば手元のmasterブランチを更新できますが、

リモートリポジトリにmaster, newversionの二つのブランチがあり、それら2つの更新を手元に取り込むには
どうすればいいのでしょうか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

１つずつpullすればいいような？

```
# 作業ブランチをmasterにして
$ git checkout master

# upstreamにあるmasterブランチの更新分を、今の作業ブランチ(=master)に取り込む
$ git pull upstream master 

# んで、次に作業ブランチをnewversionにして
$ git checkout newversion

# upstreamにあるnewversionブランチの更新分を、今の作業ブランチ(=newversion)に取り込む
$ git pull upstream newversion
```